# Передача параметров из Activity в View. Android

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Подскажите как передать значение переменной из MainActivity в View которое находится в отдельном классе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

пишешь метод в классе своей вьюхи:

```
public void setData(Data data);
```

потом вызываешь:

```
final Data data = new Data();
myView.setData(data);
```

Все, никакой магии.